# Convert Private JWK to private.pem

Tags: jwt, pem, jwk, rs256

I have generated a public/private JWS Key Pair and I need to convert my private key to a .pem file to sign my JWT using RS256 Algorithm.

Is there a solution for this?

I dont mind using like bash scripts etc, I am writing in .NET though if there is a way to do it in the code. Just anything expect an online converter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, I found a website with a NodeJS script on it and it worked a treat!

https://www.jvt.me/posts/2019/12/10/node-jwk-to-x509-pem/